# How can I scale Rectangles in Javascript with the elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem in Javascript: I have an array which changes his elements in each step when I´m clicking with the mouse. My array has for example 5 elements. Now I want to draw 5 rectangles and I want each of the rectangles to have the height of an element of this array. Then I click with the mouse, so the elements change and so the heights change too. How can I realize this?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `Getter` and a `Setter`. Here an example:

```js
const data = {
  _arr: [],
  set arr(value) {
    this._arr = value;
    //inform me
    console.log("changed");
  },
  get arr() {
    return this._arr;
  }
};

data.arr = [1, 3];
```